# React beautiful DnD- Nested list, but no need to drag between parent lists

Tags: reactjs, nested-lists, react-beautiful-dnd

I am currently trying to use React Beautiful DnD to create a draggable list of container objects. Within these objects, I have also built a sub-list of draggable elements. I know the library technically doesn't support nested lists, but I have seen many work-arounds and I believe my use-case is even simpler than most, since I **don't need to drag sublist items between parent list items.**

As of now, I have created a DnDList module so that I can re-use the code for both draggable lists. Here is what the UI looks like, with both lists circled (and variable names blacked-out):

> image (not available yet, I will share when its cleared)

The numbers circled in red are part of the parent list, which are working as expected. I can easily drag and re-order these bigger div containers without issue. **The list circled in blue, however, is causing problems.**

This sub-list is made up of simple `<p>` elements, and I actually am able to drag and re-order them, but there is a weird issue where I cannot continuously drag these items. I can click on an item (i.e. `AlphaCase`) and drag it once, but once it has been dropped, *I must click anywhere within the parent list before I can drag it again*. On first click AFTER dragging a nested list element, it incorrectly tries to drag the surrounding parent element and re-order the parent list. Once I have clicked on anything within the parent list, however, I can again drag and re-order the sub-list components. This process repeats after each nested list drag. (Strangely, clicking outside of the parent list, i.e. the `Start` button, does not count. Perhaps this 'reset click' has something to do with focus?)

Here is the code for my DnDList component:

```
<DragDropContext onDragEnd={handleDragEnd}>
  <Droppable droppableId={droppableId}>
    {(provided) => (
      <ol
        ref={provided.innerRef}
        {...provided.droppableProps}
        className={classes.root}
      >
        {React.Children.map(
          children,
          (child: React.ReactElement | undefined, index: number) => {
            if (child) {
              const keyVal: string = getAttributeKey(child.props);
              return (
                <Draggable key={keyVal} draggableId={keyVal} index={index}>
                  {(provided, snapshot) => (
                    <li
                      ref={provided.innerRef}
                      {...provided.draggableProps}
                      {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                    >
                      {child}
                    </li>
                  )}
                </Draggable>
              );
            }
          }
        )}
        {provided.placeholder}
      </ol>
    )}
  </Droppable>
</DragDropContext>
```

And here is what it looks like in use:

```
<DnDList
  handleDragEnd={handleOnDragEnd}
  droppableId="experiments"
  getAttributeKey={getAttributeKey}
>
  {<array>.map(
    (experiment: string, index: number) => (
      <p key={index} className={classes.experiment}>
        {experiment}
      </p>
    )
  )}
</DnDList>
```

The `getAttributeKey` function just returns a unique identifier (string) to use as a key for each Draggable object.

For both the parent and the sub-list elements, the getAttributeKey and handleOnDragEnd functions are practically the same:

```
const handleOnDragEnd = (result: DropResult) => {
  if (!result.destination) {
    return;
  }
  const newOrder: string[] = Array.from(...);
  const [reorderedItem] = newOrder.splice(result.source.index, 1);
  newOrder.splice(result.destination.index, 0, reorderedItem);

  onChange(...);
};

const getAttributeKey = (props: any) => {
  return props.children;
};
```

(I removed any sensitive variable names and replaced them with '...')

Again, I don't even need to drag the sub-list elements into another element of the parent list, I only need to be able to drag them within that specific sub-list.